# Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

Am facing the below error,

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.test/com.activities.ViewActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML
>   file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

XML File,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.activities.ViewActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <fragment class="com.fragments.ViewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/details_frag"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>

</FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your java code too

Comment: `com.fragments.ViewFragment` does exist this class ?

Comment: yes, it does exist

Comment: Look further on in the stack trace for the root Exception.

Answer (score 2):

The stacktrace says “Error inflating class fragment”, so there must be an issue with your fragment tag in the layout file.The XML should look like this:

```
  <fragment 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:name="com.fragments.ViewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/details_frag"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </fragment>
```

And Check the `name` attribute. Verify that your fragment lives in the package your specified and has the exact name that you specified.

If that doesn’t work, please post the full stacktrace and I’ll help to troubleshoot.

I hope it will help for you

Answer (score 0):

Use the FrameLayout as your FragmentHolder and add the fragment dynamically using the FragmentTransaction in your Activity to this fragmentHolder.

Remove the fragment inside looks like thats having issues as per your build.gradle file.

Please kindly ensure that you add it as per your requirements such as adding it to the backstack and all.